# Object is colliding but not appearing on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

The goal is to have one object move to another in 2D.
So I have two objects a squirrel and an apple.
Both objects have boxcollider2d and rigidbody2d.
Is Trigger is unchecked
Is Kinematic is unchecked.

Squirrel has the script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveToApple : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform apple;
public float speed = 5.0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, apple.position, speed*Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

So for some reason when the apple has istrigger checked you will see the squirrel move to the apple.
But if you uncheck is trigger the squirrel will disappear but it will collide with the apple.

Could someone please explain to me why this is happening?
And/Or how I could fix it so the squirrel can move to the apple, while being visible, without having is trigger checked.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in my project and it's working.

Make sure your timeScale in not 0

set you timeScale in start

```
void Start()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
}
```

or try removing the Time.deltaTime that is multiplied to the speed at the end of the MoveTowards function.

Comment: Oh thank you but now my Apple disappears. )): and squirrel goes off screen O.O

Comment: The objects don't need to be marked as triggers, so uncheck the trigger. And try lowering the speed value to something like 1.0f, that might work.